# node-gyp configure error on centos

Tags: c++, node.js

I am using Centos 6.6 installed on the server and trying to use node-gyp but I get a error when I am using the command node-gyp configure, the python version I am using is 2.7.8 and GCC C++ compiler. The Error I get is mentioned below.

```
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok

gyp info using node-gyp@1.0.2

gyp info using node@0.10.35 | linux | x64

gyp info spawn python

gyp info spawn args [ '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',

gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',

gyp info spawn args   '-f',

gyp info spawn args   'make',

gyp info spawn args   '-I',

gyp info spawn args   '/root/build/config.gypi',

gyp info spawn args   '-I',

gyp info spawn args   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',

gyp info spawn args   '-I',

gyp info spawn args   '/root/.node-gyp/0.10.35/common.gypi',

gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',

gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',

gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/root/.node-gyp/0.10.35',

gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/root',

gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',

gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',

gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',

gyp info spawn args   'build',

gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.' ]

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py", line 18, in 
    sys.exit(gyp.script_main())

  File "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/__init__.py", line 534, in script_main
    return main(sys.argv[1:])

  File "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/__init__.py", line 527, in main

    return gyp_main(args)

  File "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/__init__.py", line 503, in gyp_main

    options.circular_check)

  File "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/__init__.py", line 129, in Load

    params['parallel'], params['root_targets'])

  File "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/input.py", line 2692, in Load

    variables, includes, depth, check, True)

  File "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/input.py", line 362, in LoadTargetBuildFile
    includes, True, check)

  File "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/input.py", line 219, 

in LoadOneBuildFile

    None)

  File "binding.gyp", line 1

    {

     ^

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

gyp ERR! configure error

gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1

gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-

gyp/lib/configure.js:343:16)

gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)

gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit 

(child_process.js:820:12)

gyp ERR! System Linux 2.6.32-504.3.3.el6.x86_64

gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/node-gyp" "configure"

gyp ERR! cwd /root

gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.35

gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v1.0.2

gyp ERR! not ok
```

Comment: As the error says, you have a syntax error in your `binding.gyp`. Can you post that file?

Comment: I have used the syntax as shown in the link https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp

Comment: Well, without seeing the exact `binding.gyp` you are using, it's hard to tell exactly what the syntax problem is.

Comment: The code I have used for binding.gyp is {
  "targets": [
    {
      "target_name": "binding",
      "sources": [ "src/binding.cc" ]
    }
  ]
}

Comment: Did you happen to edit this file on Windows? This could be a problem with `\r` carriage return characters inside the file. You could remove any `\r` characters using sed or something like `dos2unix` (available via yum) just to be sure.

Comment: I have used the code $ cat bynding.gyp | sed 's/\r$//' | od -c and

Comment: and then when I run node-gyp configure I still get the same error  cat binding.gyp | sed 's/\r$//' | od -c
0000000   {  \n           "   t   a   r   g   e   t   s   "   :       [
0000020  \n                   {  \n                           "   t   a
0000040   r   g   e   t   _   n   a   m   e   "   :       "   b   i   n
0000060   d   i   n   g   "   ,  \n                           "   s   o
0000100   u   r   c   e   s   "   :       [       "   s   r   c   /   b
0000120   i   n   d   i   n   g   .   c   c   "       ]  \n
0000140       }  \n           ]  \n   }
0000150

Comment: File "binding.gyp", line 1
    {
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:343:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:820:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 2.6.32-504.3.3.el6.x86_64
gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/node-gyp" "configure"
gyp ERR! cwd /root
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.35
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v1.0.2
gyp ERR! not ok

Comment: Ok, you piped binding.gyp to sed, but did you actually write the output of sed back to binding.gyp?