# node-gyp-build: npm install sodium-native error; what is exit code 1?

Tags: node.js, npm, node-gyp, gyp, hypercore-protocol

I am attempting to install [sodium native](https://sodium-friends.github.io/docs/docs/getstarted) as an npm package on OpenBSD 7.3 amd64.

*Aside: As a dependency of [Hypercore, Hyperbee and Corestore](https://docs.holepunch.to/).*

This needs [node-gyp](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#readme).

Following [this](https://obsd.solutions/en/blog/2022/02/23/node-sass-build-fails-on-openbsd-how-to-fix/), I set the C and C++ compilers to clang:

```
export CC=clang
export CXX=clang++
```

I created a directory `example` and, for development/debugging only, I set the permissions via `chmod 777`.

I then used `npm init` to create an empty `package.json` file.

On running `npm install sodium-native`, I get the following error logs:

```
395 info run sodium-native@4.0.1 install node_modules/sodium-native node-gyp-build
396 info run sodium-native@4.0.1 install { code: 1, signal: null }
397 timing reify:rollback:createSparse Completed in 4183ms
398 timing reify:rollback:retireShallow Completed in 0ms
399 timing command:install Completed in 31258ms
400 verbose stack Error: command failed
400 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@npmcli/promise-spawn/lib/index.js:53:27)
400 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
400 verbose stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1091:16)
400 verbose stack     at Socket.<anonymous> (node:internal/child_process:449:11)
400 verbose stack     at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
400 verbose stack     at Pipe.<anonymous> (node:net:322:12)
401 verbose pkgid sodium-native@4.0.1
402 verbose cwd /example
403 verbose OpenBSD 7.3
404 verbose node v18.15.0
405 verbose npm  v9.5.0
406 error code 1
407 error path /example/node_modules/sodium-native
408 error command failed
409 error command sh -c node-gyp-build
410 error gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
410 error gyp info using node-gyp@9.3.1
410 error gyp info using node@18.15.0 | openbsd | x64
410 error gyp info find Python using Python version 3.10.11 found at "/usr/local/bin/python3"
410 error gyp info spawn /usr/local/bin/python3
410 error gyp info spawn args [
410 error gyp info spawn args   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
410 error gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
410 error gyp info spawn args   '-f',
410 error gyp info spawn args   'make',
410 error gyp info spawn args   '-I',
410 error gyp info spawn args   '/example/node_modules/sodium-native/build/config.gypi',
410 error gyp info spawn args   '-I',
410 error gyp info spawn args   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
410 error gyp info spawn args   '-I',
410 error gyp info spawn args   '/root/.cache/node-gyp/18.15.0/include/node/common.gypi',
410 error gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
410 error gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
410 error gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/root/.cache/node-gyp/18.15.0',
410 error gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-gyp',
410 error gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/root/.cache/node-gyp/18.15.0/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
410 error gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/example/node_modules/sodium-native',
410 error gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
410 error gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
410 error gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
410 error gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
410 error gyp info spawn args   'build',
410 error gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
410 error gyp info spawn args ]
410 error node:events:491
410 error       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
410 error       ^
410 error
410 error Error: write EPIPE
410 error     at WriteWrap.onWriteComplete [as oncomplete] (node:internal/stream_base_commons:94:16)
410 error Emitted 'error' event on Socket instance at:
410 error     at Socket.onerror (node:internal/streams/readable:785:14)
410 error     at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
410 error     at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
410 error     at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
410 error     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
410 error   errno: -32,
410 error   code: 'EPIPE',
410 error   syscall: 'write'
410 error }
410 error
410 error Node.js v18.15.0
410 error gyp: Call to 'node deps/bin.js --print-include' returned exit status 1 while in binding.gyp. while trying to load binding.gyp
410 error gyp ERR! configure error 
410 error gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
410 error gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:325:16)
410 error gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
410 error gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)
410 error gyp ERR! System OpenBSD 7.3
410 error gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
410 error gyp ERR! cwd /example/node_modules/sodium-native
410 error gyp ERR! node -v v18.15.0
410 error gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v9.3.1
410 error gyp ERR! not ok
411 verbose exit 1
412 timing npm Completed in 31440ms
413 verbose unfinished npm timer reify 1683196282136
414 verbose unfinished npm timer reify:build 1683196305333
415 verbose unfinished npm timer build 1683196305334
416 verbose unfinished npm timer build:deps 1683196305334
417 verbose unfinished npm timer build:run:install 1683196305349
418 verbose unfinished npm timer build:run:install:node_modules/sodium-native 1683196307572
419 verbose code 1
420 error A complete log of this run can be found in:
420 error     /root/.npm/_logs/2023-05-04T10_31_22_018Z-debug-0.log
```

The node_modules directory did not get created. I am unsure how to interpret this. I think perhaps that node-gyp is not finding binding.gyp. I note that there is a binding.gyp in [the repo](https://github.com/sodium-friends/sodium-native/blob/2d816f820dd73f715b74f0d14e8208565dff27c3/binding.gyp). Could there be an error in how it is downloaded? Where should it be on my system (`find . -name "binding.gyp"` implies that it is within the node-pledge module `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-pledge/binding.gyp`), is this right?

What does error code 1 mean? What might be going wrong here? What next steps could I take?

---

There are a lot of questions with this error on SE, but no good explanations of what is going on and why. Is there a high level process description that would help; e.g. what is GYP doing? what is node-gyp doing, and what is node-gyp-build doing?

---

Here are a small portion of the questions with this error:

| OS tags | question |
| --- | --- |
| [centos](/questions/tagged/centos) | [node-gyp rebuild - Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39598906/node-gyp-rebuild-error-gyp-failed-with-exit-code-1) /// [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28394645/node-gyp-configure-error-on-centos|](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28394645/node-gyp-configure-error-on-centos%7C) |
| [debian](/questions/tagged/debian) | [Node-RED - Node install - Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59681355/node-red-node-install-error-gyp-failed-with-exit-code-1) /// [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74037736/node-red-npm-gyp-fails-node-installation-with-exit-code-1|](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74037736/node-red-npm-gyp-fails-node-installation-with-exit-code-1%7C) |
| [macos](/questions/tagged/macos) | https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64454556/command-node-gyp-rebuild-exit-code-1 /// [ERROR in Cannot find module 'node-sass'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48147896/error-in-cannot-find-module-node-sass) /// [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29023316/node-gyp-pkg-config-command-not-found-on-mac-10-5-8-during-npm-install|](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29023316/node-gyp-pkg-config-command-not-found-on-mac-10-5-8-during-npm-install%7C) |
| [ubuntu](/questions/tagged/ubuntu) | https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21155922/error-installing-node-gyp-on-ubuntu |
| [windows](/questions/tagged/windows) | [How to fix Node-gyp MSBuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57047392/how-to-fix-node-gyp-msbuild-exe-failed-with-exit-code-1) /// [Node-GYP failed with exit code: 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47285532/node-gyp-failed-with-exit-code-1) /// [Windows 10 node-gyp cannot build: MSBUILD failed with exit code 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31817447/windows-10-node-gyp-cannot-build-msbuild-failed-with-exit-code-1) /// [NPM install fails with node-gyp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33896511/npm-install-fails-with-node-gyp) /// [Cannot install node modules that require compilation on Windows 7 x64/VS2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14278417/cannot-install-node-modules-that-require-compilation-on-windows-7-x64-vs2012) /// [npm install with error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49348482/npm-install-with-error-gyp-failed-with-exit-code-1) /// [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58859338/unable-to-install-leveldown-npm-package-node-gyp-error-msbuild-exe-failed-with|](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58859338/unable-to-install-leveldown-npm-package-node-gyp-error-msbuild-exe-failed-with%7C) |

https://github.com/prebuild/node-gyp-build/issues/8

https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/809

---

Note: this is an [adapted cross-post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/65943/200228) of [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/744907/openbsd-npm-install-sodium-native-interpret-error-messages).

Comment: Further investigation: https://github.com/sodium-friends/sodium-native/issues/178

Comment: have you solve it? I had the same issue with npm-gyp

Comment: @nawar, I did get it to install using [this approach](https://github.com/sodium-friends/sodium-native/issues/178#issuecomment-1539960417), perhaps it'll work for npm-gyp too...

Comment: node-gyp ** ,,, thanks  will try